# Pip install package prior to setup() in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers, setup.py

I have some `.proto` gRPC files I want to compile as part of the setup.py script. This requires running `from grpc_tools import protoc` and calling `protoc` *before* `setup(args)`. The goal is to compile and install the pb files from `pip install pkgname`.

E.g.

```py
# setup.py

# generate our pb2 files in the temp directory structure
compile_protobufs(pkgname)

# this will package the generated files and put them in site-packages or .whl
setup(
    name=pkgname,
    install_requires=['grpcio-tools', ...],
    ...
)
```

This works as intended, I get the pb files in my site-packages or in the wheel without them having to exist in the source folder. However, this pattern means I cannot naively `pip install pkgname` from scratch, as the step `compile_protobufs` depends on `grpcio-tools`, which does not get installed until `setup()`.

I could use setup_requires, but [that is on the chopping block](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/). I could just install the dependencies first (right now I use `RUN pip install -r build-require.txt && pip install pkgname/` ), but it still seems like there ought to be a cleaner way.

Am I even going about this pattern correctly or am I missing some packaging idiom?

My criteria:

- Generally this is run inside a container, so minimizing external deps
- I want the `_pb2.py` files regenerated each time I `pip install`
- These files need to also make their way into any `.whl` or tar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it is already documented here:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/tools/distrib/python/grpcio_tools#usage

So your `setup.py` could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import distutils.command.install
import setuptools

class build_package_protos(setuptools.Command):
    user_options = []
    def initialize_options(self):
        pass
    def finalize_options(self):
        pass
    def run(self):
        from grpc_tools import command
        command.build_package_protos(self.distribution.package_dir[''])

class install(distutils.command.install.install):
    _sub_command = ('build_package_protos', None,)
    _sub_commands = distutils.command.install.install.sub_commands
    sub_commands = [_sub_command] + _sub_commands

def setup():
    setuptools.setup(
        # see 'setup.cfg'
        cmdclass={
            'build_package_protos': build_package_protos,
            'install': install,
        },
        setup_requires=[
            'grpcio-tools',
        ],
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

Comment: "Note that this particular approach requires grpcio-tools to be installed on the machine before the setup script is invoked (i.e. no combination of setup_requires or install_requires will provide access to grpc.tools.command.BuildPackageProtos if it isn't already installed). One way to work around this can be found in our grpcio-health-checking package"

So this told me what I need to know. I'm still concerned about `setup_requires` being deprecated, but I should be able to port this knowledge to `pyproject.toml` style builds.

Comment: I haven't worked with _PEP518_ / _PEP517_ / `pyproject.toml`, but I expect it to solve these kinds of issues even more elegantly. It will actually depend on the _build backend_ you select.
I haven't seen how to add custom build step to either `flit` nor `poetry`, but `setuptools` as a build backend should still be a viable choice for quite a while.