# Creating a python library to distribute proto definitions

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to create a python library to distribute my proto definitions to users and want that the python stubs are generated at the time of library installation when they do `pip install protolib`.

Following is a preview of my code structure:

```
Tree of: /root/protolib
.
|__src
| |__requirements.txt
| |__protos
| | |__helloworld.proto
| |__stubs
| |__setup.py
```

I want that python stubs are generated in the `stubs` directory at the time of `pip install`. I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57579888/pip-install-package-prior-to-setup-in-setup-py) and was able to create a wheel but the stubs are getting generated at the time of wheel creation and are being written in the `protos` directory in my source code repo. This is because the function `command.build_package_protos()` in `grpc_tools` package of the `grpc` [library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/32b43f016817fd8a1ed74d07ec2740a72017b58a/tools/distrib/python/grpcio_tools/grpc_tools/command.py#L35) use one same location for `proto_path`, `python_out`, and `grpc_python_out` i.e. `inclusion_root`. If changing the location for the generated stubs is not possible, then I think I am ready to move my `.proto` files to the `stubs` directory so that users are still able to import them from `stubs` (as shown below as end goal). But I still want my source code repo free of generated stubs i.e. the stubs should be generated only at the time of `pip install`.

The end goal is to enable the user to import stubs like:

```
from stubs import helloworld_pb2, helloworld_pb2_grpc
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902139/7976758 Please note: "*The solution … **only works when installing a source distribution zip or tarball**, or installing in editable mode from a source tree. **It will not work when installing from a binary wheel (`.whl`)***"